# Angular - UI-Select (Select 2) Height

Tags: angular-ui, ui-select2

How do you set the height of the Angular UI-Select widget when an item is selected.  I have a custom template for the selected item that includes an image and stuff and it gets cut-off.

Is there an option somewhere?  I feel like it should expand to fit the template.

Comment: Do you still need this answered?

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed this by using the css like

```css
.ui-select-choices .item {
    height: auto !important
}
```

and using the `!important` css function because ui-select has a lot of inline styles and it gets very tedious to fix. If you are using your own template, try not to use the `.item` class and use something unique like `.select-choice-item` Next time you might want to provide the structure in the template you're using so we can answer you with a more specific solution.